# How can I fix this broken cluster mailbox unit (CBU)?

Tags: mailbox

Someone hit our community's mailbox and trying to get it fixed has become a major nightmare.  Basically, when it was hit, the aluminum pedestal was snapped off right at the base.  I have an idea on how to fix it, but it involves building a wood pedestal with a 4x4, mounting it to a 4x4 bracket, and then mounting that bracket into the concrete.  I've tried removing this base, but these nuts are in really good.

Being that I am the HOA president, it's my duty to find a fix for this ASAP, so I am hoping some of you can assist me here.

Edit:  BTW, I called the original manufacturer and they do not make replacement parts for this discontinued 1997 model.

[image]

Comment: To remove the base from the concrete, heat the nuts with a torch, let cool, heat again and turn while still warm.

Comment: What about calling a welder to repair what you've got rather than trying to replace the broken piece?

Comment: @mac That's a great idea.  I am going to check Angie's List.

Comment: Does Angie know any welders? Seems like they might travel in different circles. Good luck.

Comment: Absolutely either repair the base or weld up a replacement. Introducing wood will result in a rickety structure. You will need to get the base off somehow or design a replacement base to work around it because it's impractical to field weld aluminum. Any breeze blows away the shield gas, resulting in lousy welds.

Comment: @bcworkz It appears that you're right about the breeze blowing away the shild gas.  I have a welder coming out tonight to "fix" this problem, but now you have me worried.  What types of questions should I ask this guy to ensure he's going to do it right?  Does this problem apply to specific welding equipment or type of metal?  Should he put up some kind of wind shield?  I found this guy on Angie's List, but he's doing this on the side (his full-time job is welding) and I don't want to regret this, but I also need a mailbox ASAP, so I am willing to take some risk.

Comment: I'm not a welder, like many things, I know something of it but am not an expert. Aluminum needs to be shielded when welding. How that is achieved depends on the equipment used. The best way to weld aluminum is TIG, that is not much of a field technique. MIG will work, but the shield is fragile. I'd be afraid any wind break would just redirect which way the shield is blown away. If you're lucky and there's no wind at all, it may just work. Note it is also very difficult to weld thin metal to thick metal. I believe even stick welding is possible in theory. The results cannot be very satisfactory

Comment: Damn character limits X/ I really think your best course of action is to shop fabricate a base, then bolt it into place on location. A base could be made to straddle the existing and anchored with new expansion bolts if removal of the current base is an issue. Such a shop built base will be far better built than trying to patch the old one together in the field. Sure there's extra time driving back and forth, but the rest is time spent either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know who hit it, buy a new mailbox, and **send them the bill.** They are **liable.**

If you don't know who hit it, there's more incentive to save a buck by fixing this one, since most insurance companies will raise your rates if you file for a hit and run, and the raised rates will cost more than just fixing it.

If you can't get the nuts off, either cut them off (if you use a nut-splitter the studs may still be usable) and haul the whole base in to a welder, or have them make a whole new base (the post is pretty thin and may not weld well) and drill holes for new anchors to park it beside the old one.

[image: nut=splitter]

Put anti-seize on the new nuts - someone will thank you (or your ghost) the next time this happens.